# Separate keys for encryption and MAC?

Tags: mac, hmac, authenticated-encryption

I use HMAC(ciphertext)+ciphertext for authenticated encryption.

The same key is used for both MAC and encryption.

Is that right? Is using separate keys for MAC and encryption necessary or any good?

I ask this beacause I have read somewhere that keys used for one role shouldn't be used for the other role.